# Safely catch API crashing/exiting

Tags: c#

I am using a third party electrical solver into my C# program trough its API.

My problem is that the third party software sometimes closes when the network license is unavailable.

The program tech support say that this is because an exit signal is sent when the license is unavailable.

Right now, when the third party software closes, my program closes as well. Is there any way to avoid this?

A sample code would be this:

```
public class PF_Interface {

    WApi apiInstance;

    public void CreateAPI() {
        apiInstance = WApi.WCreateApiInstance();
    }
}
```

If the program is unavailable the line `apiInstance = WApi.WCreateApiInstance();` will not return anything, and the execution goes no further.

I would like to run the API independently from my program somehow, so when it closes, my program remains running.

Comment: What happens when you create the api on a different thread?

Comment: I'll try, and report back.

Comment: Why does your program close when theirs does?

Comment: Using the mixed-mode debugger, put a breakpoint on the `ExitProcess` function in `kernel32.dll` (well, it was there, newer versions of Windows it will be in one of the `winbase`* DLLs).  See what the stack trace is.  If it really is a signal, you can install a handler, but I suspect the tech meant the program calls the C runtime function `exit`.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Loaded the DLL in-process and it calls `exit` or `abort` instead of returning, apparently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clean option here is to use two processes.

The dirty option is to use Microsoft Detours or a similar hooking technique to catch the call to `ExitProcess` and throw an exception you can catch in your own code.  No telling what the state of the library will be in, though, so don't count on being able to try again later after the license becomes available.

Comment: Putting the API creation in another thread seems to be effective since now I can show a MessageBox with the problem.